# How to merge array of objects to objects with unique key using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I merge `arr1` array of objects to the `obj` with unique key id's, My aim is to receive one array which will contain data structured like this `[{ItemID: "164488786030", name:'google', promotion_id: 7, name2:'google-mt'}]`, I can't figure out how i can solve this using ES6 syntax, Any advice would be acceptable to me, thanks.

```js
let arr1 = [{ItemID: "164488786031", name:'google'}, {ItemID:"164488786030", name:'facebook'}]

let obj = {164488786031: {promotion_id: 7, name2:'google-mt'}, 164488786030: {promotion_id: 9, name2:'facebook-mt'}}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You have an object with two similar keys. What's the expected result?

Comment: @jabaa,  I have updated question

Comment: Please read [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ You can solve this with Array#map

Comment: `obj.164488786031.ItemID = 164488786030; return [obj.164488786031];` would do what you describe but I suspect this is not what you had in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```js
const arr1 = [{ItemID: "164488786031", name:'google'}, 
              {ItemID:"164488786030", name:'facebook'}] ,
      obj = {164488786031: {promotion_id: 7, name2:'google-mt'}, 
             164488786030: {promotion_id: 9, name2:'facebook-mt'}};
      
const res = arr1.map(e=>({ItemID:e.ItemID, name:e.name, promotion_id: obj[e.ItemID].promotion_id, name2:obj[e.ItemID].name2 })); 
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I have now ... ;-)